# $scope is updated, but the view is not

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 states. A `home` state and a child of the home state called, `suggestions`. The home state loads a template into a `ui-view` element.

Inside my home template, and my suggestions template I have this link,

```
.addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie(movie)"}
```

This link fires the `.addMovie` function. This places a new value in my database and after that's done reloads all the data with this,

```
var init = function(){

  movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
    $scope.movies = response.data;

    var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
    $scope.orderedMovies = orderBy($scope.movies, "release_date", false);

    var movies = $scope.orderedMovies
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 8, movieGroups=[];
    for (i=0,j=movies.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = movies.slice(i,i+chunk);
        movieGroups.push(temparray);
    }
    $scope.movieGroups = movieGroups
  })

  $(".search_results").fadeOut(250);
  $('body').find('#search_input').val("");

  movieTrailers.loadTrailers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.trailers = response.data;

  })

  movieSuggestions.loadSuggestions().then(function(response) {
    $scope.suggestions = response.data;
  })

  console.log ('init end')
}
```

So if I add a movie from within my home template, the view updates with the new data.

In this home template I also have a button that loads the suggestions state,

```
#suggestions

  %a{"ui-sref" => ".suggestions"}
    %h1
      Suggestions
  %div{"ui-view" => "suggestions"}
```

This loads the suggestions template inside the suggestions view inside the home state.

In my suggestions template I have the same button as in the home state.

```
.addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie(movie)"}
```

And when I click that it does do the `addMovie` function because I get the console logs in my console, and also it reloads all the data (with use of the `init` function) because when I check the network tab and view the movies.json it has the new data. But it does not update my home template view. To see the new data in my home template I have to refresh the page.

Comment: You may need to call `$scope.$apply()` when the update happens.

Comment: You need to remove `$(".search_results").fadeOut(250); $('body').find('#search_input').val("");`.

Comment: I'd try initializing anything on $scope that will be used in any asynchronous processes.  At the top of `init`, have `$scope.movies = []; $scope.movieGroups = []; $scope.trailers = []; $scope.suggestions = [];`.  It might be a case of Angular not binding correctly to those due to them being undefined in the template at the time of compilation.

Comment: @JeremyJackson  I tried to wrap the functions inside the `init` in apply() but it gave me a `[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` error in the console.

Comment: @kevrom could you expand on the answer a bit?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Try putting `$scope.movies = []; $scope.movieGroups = []; $scope.trailers = []; $scope.suggestions = [];` right after `var init = function(){`.

At the time of template compilation, those properties of $scope are undefined in the template due to them being assigned only after your asynchronous API calls.  Angular won't be able to bind them properly, so that may be why your template isn't updating but the values are.

Comment: Hm, I assign my 'addMovieCtrl` controller to the suggestions view because I thought it needed that controller. But it looked like I allready assigned the `addMovieCtrl` through the home state view. Removing the controller from the `suggestions` view fixed the problem.